# date time conversion forthis format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date time column in 20210809125249 this format has to be converted to
MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI: SS how this can be done. in oracle sql

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: What is the data type of your "date-time" column?

Comment: What is a "date time column"? What do you mean by "converted to MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI: SS"?

Comment: This can be done by writing *some* code that is missing in the question, so you will have a starting point that either works as expected or returns unexpected results/throws an error. Then you may edit your question and ask how to resolve that error or why the result is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use build in function:
[to_date()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can consecutively apply `TO_DATE()` and then `TO_CHAR()` such as

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(theColumn,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
   FROM theTable
```

in order to display as desired, presuming the first eight character represents ISO-8601-similar format(`YYYY-MM-DD`) for date values